# ssh git clone ask for password

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I'am trying to clone from **our** gitlab server using ssh

I've set ssh public key

and when I try to clone

```
git@192.168.0.15:root/voice_authentication_webui.git
```

it ask me **password**

[image]

why is that ?

also I get below when I issue this

```
ssh -Tv git@192.168.0.12
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add the public SSH key to GitLab user 'root' account?

Comment: How did you configure your local ssh client? Do you use ssh-agent? Or did you save the key to filesystem? Hace you double-checked the documentation to ensure you did not miss a step?

Comment: @VonC I just add public key to my account , is it different from root account 
I'am one of many developers in this project .

Comment: i used **ssh-keygen -t rsa** to generate ssh key and public key is saved in **/c/Users/dezh/.ssh/id_rsa.pub** and i can see it . @criztovyl

Answer (score 1):

> just add public key to my account , is it different from root account I'am one of many developers in this project

- check that the authentication works with:

  ```
  ssh -Tv git@192.168.0.15
  ```
- check that [you are a member](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/) on the root/voice_authentication_webui.git repository

For your test, you could use a key without passphrase.

But most importantly, check your gitlab.rb for a `gitlab_rails['gitlab_ssh_host'] = 'xxx'` directive.
That would make sure SSH is listening and managed by GitLab.

Comment: OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.12 [192.168.0.12] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dezh/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/dezh/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1

Comment: i got this @Vonce

Comment: @kevin You should see a [Welcome message](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#verify-that-you-can-connect)

Comment: also I am member of project because i can make a branch in project from website

Comment: no i dont see welcome message @VonC

I also added full result of ssh -Tv git@192.168.0.15 in question body 

you can see it might help

Comment: @kevin I suspect this is a gitlab.rb configuration issue. How is GitLab server installed (which version on whic platform) Is this a Docker-based omnibus installation?

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem. It was solved by this post [SSH Key: no mutual signature algorithm](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/qgmnnh/comment/hi785p9/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). thanks [stormcloud-9](https://www.reddit.com/user/stormcloud-9/)!

> RSA is deprecated. You can force the ssh client to use it by using `-o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa` (you can put it in ~/.ssh/config too), or with the preferred solution you can create a ed25519 key by passing `-t ed25519` to ssh-keygen.